# Extending a custom Experience Profile tab

Tags: experience-profile

I'm using `Sitecore 9.0.1`, I was able to create a custom tab in the experience profile by following [this](https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/EPExpressTab).
However, now i want to add subtabs and Data tables inside them so i'm following [this article](https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/04/19/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-speak-app/), However, I can't reach this path 
`/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/PageSettings/Tabs`

so i can't find this "Tabs" folder! Any clue what i'm missing?

Comment: Can you add screenshot from Sitecore Rocks from the point where you cannot "reach" that path? Are you sure you are in "Core" database?

Comment: When you say can't reach this path? Where in the path do you stumble? guessing it is as @PeterProchazka suggets that you may not be looking at core database.

Comment: @Peter Prochazka YESS! Actually i wans't in the core DB! thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can find that item in "core" database.

From Sitecore Rocks:

[image]

From Sitecore you can open Launchpad and go to Desktop:

[image]

Switch context database to "core" from the db selector located in bottom right corner of your screen:

[image]

Go to Content Editor and navigate to `/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/PageSettings/Tabs` item:

[image]

....

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot. I have another question please. I want to create a new "Tab" but i can't find the "Tab" template when i use "insert from template" option. any idea?

Comment: It should be this one:  /sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 1/Templates/Common/Tab

Comment: You can also duplicate existing Tab like Overview or Activity which you can find underneath `Tabs` item